# Impersonating users of Drive of one domain as a domain administrator

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to impersonate users of a google app domain using a admin user. I could do it easily with google data document list api but I cant find a way to do it with the new Drive API.

Precisely, what I want to do is authenticate my admin user using Oauth2 (i've already done this), retrieve a list of the users of my domain and then impersonate my users, or at least be able to access files and docs from the Drive of those users.

In the administrative panel of google apps, there are Oauth consumer key and Oauth consumer secret, but these are used in Oauth1 2LO, not Oauth2.

Is there a proper way/workaround/hack to implement what I want ?

Best regards,

Jérôme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only been looking at the google-api-ruby-client as an example but you should be able to do this with a service account that is permitted access through the admin panel -> Advanced tools -> manage third party oauath clients. Once permitted you can follow the example for a service account here http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/service_account/analytics.rb?repo=samples but instead of authorizing with

```
client.authorization = asserter.authorize()
```

you can use

```
client.authorization = asserter.authorize("id@domain.com")
```

I haven't done a lot with this yet but after authenticating in this method I've been able to list all documents owned by a user on my domain.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to James Woodward, i've been able to impersonate user. I post an answer to provide Java specific details.

1. Create a service account in the API console. 3 important resources are created :

   1. Client ID : used to authorize the app on the Google Apps domain
   2. Email address : used to authorize the requests of the app
   3. .p12 key file : used to authorize the requests of the app
2. Authorize the app on the Google Apps Administrative panel, providing it with Service account client ID, and all the scopes the app will need.
3. Create `GoogleCredential` this way :

   ```
   GoogleCredential serviceCred = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
               .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
               .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ID)
               .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
               .setServiceAccountUser("impersonated.user@domain.com")
               .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File("key.p12")
               .build();
   ```

Those credentials can now be used to authenticate the requests made by the app on any scope authorized.

Comment: For me, it was necessary to use only the "Drive" scope as using "DriveScopes.all()" gives you an unauthorized error. Also, I updated java client libraries to the ones found in :

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download

(google-api-client-assembly-1.21.0-1.21.0.zip at my time)